# ¿Por que un formulario no guarda datos en la base de datos usando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema para guardar datos, de manera muy sencilla.

El problema: al guardar dice que no existe la variable de conexion, a pesar de estar incluida en el archivo php, luego dice que guardo correctamente, pero no guarda nada en la base de datos

**Conexion.php:**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$usua = "root";
$pass = "";
$base = "php_practica";
$cone = new mysqli($host, $usua, $pass, $base);

if ($cone->connect_error)
    {
    die("Error de Conexion: " . $cone->connect_error);
    }

?>
```

**Formulario de registro:**

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="procesar.php">
        <h1 align="center">Bienvenido</h1>
        <a href="index.html">
            <ol>Pagina Principal</ol>
        </a>
        <a href="registrar.html">
            <ol>Registrar</ol>
        </a>
        <a href="listado.html">
            <ol>Listado</ol>
        </a>
        <a href="Sancion.html">
            <ol>Sancion</ol>
        </a>
        <div> Ingrese su nombre </div>
        <input type="text" name="nombre">

        <div> Ingrese su apellido </div>
        <input type="text" name="apellido">

        <div> Ingrese su cedula </div>
        <input type="text" name="cedula">

        <div> Ingrese su rango </div>
        <div>
            <select name="rango">
                <option value="1">First</option>
                <option value="2">Second</option>
                <option value="3">Third</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</body>

</html>
```

**Procesar.php**

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
include ("funciones.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="funciones.php">
        <?php

bd_agregar($_REQUEST);
?>
</body>

</html>
```

**Funciones.php:**

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");

function bd_agregar($temp){
$nombre=$_REQUEST["nombre"];
$apellido=$_REQUEST["apellido"];
$cedula=$_REQUEST["cedula"];
$rango=$_REQUEST["rango"];
mysqli_query($cone,"INSERT INTO personal (nombre,apellido,cedula,rango)
VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");
}


//Revisar si guardo correctamente//
if (mysqli_connect_errno($cone)) 
  {
  echo "Error al guardar los datos:" . mysqli_connect_error(); 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente:";
    }

mysqli_close($cone); 
?>
```

**ERROR:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: cone in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Sistema de practica\funciones.php on line 9 --- Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Sistema de practica\funciones.php on line 10

Comment: listo hermano, agregado

Comment: lo que probe fue copiando y pegando el codigo de CONEXION.PHP dentro de las funciones, no sale error, el problema es que seria como redudante, colocar ese codigo en todos los archivos, seraalgun error del como incluyo el fichero? sigue sin guardar.
No hay problema si  trabajo con registro-procesar-funcion ?
trate eliminando la funcion y si guarda, es decir, dejando solo las variables y el sql, pero esto dentro del "PROCESAR.PHP", lo que quiero es tener un archivo con todas las funciones y luego solo llamarlas, estare pasando mal el argumento?

Comment: Me di cuenta de que los html no tenian id="x cosa"

Comment: El código de la pregunta es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en un entorno de producción. Por favor, lee [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250) y aplica las recomendaciones en las respuestas.

Comment: agrega `global $cone;` al principio de tu funcion `function bd_agregar($temp)`

Comment: Leere sobre la inyeccion para proteger el codigo

Comment: @VictorA. con la última edición has cambiado la pregunta por completo (y las respuestas dejan de tener sentido). Si tienes una nueva pregunta, postea una nueva pregunta en lugar de editar la pregunta para añadir más información que cambie el sentido de la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otro pequeño error que veo es que en tu conexión has puesto `connect_error` y deberia ser `connect_errno`

**Conexion.php**

Tu código:

```
$host="localhost";
$usua="root";
$pass="";
$base="php_practica";
$cone = new mysqli($host,$usua,$pass,$base);

if ($cone->connect_error) {
                   ^^^^^^
   die("Error de Conexion: " . $cone->connect_error);
                                              ^^^^^^
}
```

Código actualizado:

```
$host="localhost";
$usua="root";
$pass="";
$base="php_practica";

$cone = new mysqli($host,$usua,$pass,$base);

if ($cone->connect_errno) {
   echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $cone->connect_errno . ") " . $cone->connect_error;    
}
```

**Ejemplo completo probado en localhost:**

Formulario de registro:

```
<form method="POST" action ="procesar.php">        
    <label> Ingrese su nombre </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre">

    <label> Ingrese su apellido </label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido">

    <label> Ingrese su cedula </label>
    <input type="text" name="cedula">

    <label> Ingrese su rango </label>
    <div><select name="rango">
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
    </select></div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

procesar.php

```
<?php    
  require_once'conexion.php';
  include'funciones.php';

  bd_agregar($_REQUEST);

  //Cerramos conexión.
  $cone->close();     
?>
```

funciones.php

```
<?php
  require_once'conexion.php';

  //Creamos función
  function bd_agregar($temp){
    //Especificamos variable global.
    global $cone;

    //Obtenemos datos formulario
    $nombre = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_REQUEST['apellido'];
    $cedula = $_REQUEST['cedula'];
    $rango = $_REQUEST['rango'];

    //Insertamos datos
    $cone->query("INSERT INTO personal (nombre,apellido,cedula,rango) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");           
      echo $nombre.$apellido.$cedula.$rango;
  }

  //Comprobamos ejecución sentencia.
  if ($cone===false) {
    printf("Mensaje de error: %s\n", $cone->error);
  } else {
    echo "Los datos se insertaron correctamente";
  }

  //Aqui tienes el error de no insertar tus datos 
  //Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in...      
  //$cone->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo corregi, ya funciona bien la conexion, ahora lo que quiero son las funciones, porque me parece ineficiente tener todos los SQL en cada php, me parece mejor tener el archivo funcion

Comment: @VictorA. te he dejado un ejemplo completo probado en `localhost`. te dejo también el manual sobre como usar sentencias estilo orientado a objetos: **http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php**

Comment: Hermano, esta excelente el codigo que me pasaste, ahora no se que ocurre pero no inserta nada en la BD

Comment: No lanzaba error, el problema estaba en mi echo para mostrar la lista de datos de la tabla rangos, ocurria que estaba mal ordenada la secuencia de comillas , por lo tanto se pasaba un valor en blanco puesto trataba de insertar $reg["rango"].

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe al [ámbito de las variables en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php). Estás intentando acceder a una variable global desde dentro de una función sin especificar que es una variable global, entonces se busca una variable local del mismo nombre (que no existe) y recibes el fallo.

Para solucionarlo y poder usar `$cone` dentro de tu función, prueba añadiendo esto como la primera línea de la función `bd_agregar`:

```
global $cone;
```

Algo como esto:

```
function bd_agregar($temp){
  global $cone;
  $nombre=$_REQUEST["nombre"];
  $apellido=$_REQUEST["apellido"];
  $cedula=$_REQUEST["cedula"];
  $rango=$_REQUEST["rango"];
  mysqli_query($cone,"INSERT INTO personal (nombre,apellido,cedula,rango) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");
}
```

Comment: Probare asignar esa variable global, lo que hice al final fue: eliminar la funcion y colocar el procesar con ese codigo directo, pero me parece ineficiente, si corrijo eso que me dices podria tener mi funciones.php, porque agregue otras funciones pero directas en codigo

Comment: Ahora ya funciona la funcion, no da error, jajaja que redundancia, pero me da un error el MYSQLI

Answer (score 1):

Lo que veo yo es que confundes un poco los conceptos de la programación procedural y la *POO (Programación orientada a objetos)*. Para cerrar la conexión debería cerrarla de la siguiente manera `$mysqli->close();`. Otra cosa que veo es que incluyes la conexión en todos lados. Solo la deberías incluir en el **Procesar.php**.

En la consulta deberia ser asi:

```
$mysqli->query($cone,"INSERT INTO personal
(nombre,apellido,cedula,rango)
VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");
```

... y para que funcione la variable `$cone`, o la haces global, o la pasas por el argumento de la función.

Comment: Utilice esto asi:

function bd_agregar($temp){
global $cone;
$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
$apellido=$_REQUEST['apellido'];
$cedula=$_REQUEST['cedula'];
$rango=$_REQUEST['rango'];
$cone->query($cone,"INSERT INTO personal
(nombre,apellido,cedula,rango)
VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");
echo $nombre.$apellido.$cedula.$rango;
}

Pero dice que falta 1 argumento

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo segun Leo el mismo php te dice exactamente donde esta el error
buscate el archivo php:

**Funciones.php:**

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
function bd_agregar($temp){
$nombre=$_REQUEST["nombre"];
$apellido=$_REQUEST["apellido"];
$cedula=$_REQUEST["cedula"];
$rango=$_REQUEST["rango"];
**mysqli_query($cone,"INSERT INTO personal (nombre,apellido,cedula,rango)
VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$rango')");
}**
```

segun leo

> Notice: Undefined variable: cone in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Sistema de
>   practica\funciones.php on line 9 --- Warning: mysqli_query() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Sistema de
>   practica\funciones.php on line 10

tu error esta exactamente en ese archivo **Funciones.php:** en la linea **9 y 10**

la linea 9 nueva te esta diciendo que la insercion no acepta valores NULL mientas que el 10 esta es esperando un resultado X  osea es como si te faltara una linea pero en realidad es que la tabla no te permite valores Nulls. y al no ser insertada te arroja dicho error.

Ejemplo si la insercion quieres que quede asi:

```
ID    nombre  apellido cedula    rango
1     pedro   Alvarez  15600600  teniente
```

pero en tu scrip de MySQL haces esto:

INSERT INTO personal (nombre,apellido,cedula,rango) VALUES ('pedro','Alvarez','','teniente',);

Tu campo Cedula quedara en blanco:

```
ID    nombre  apellido cedula    rango
1     pedro   Alvarez            teniente
```

NOTESE que el campo ID se deberia llenar Solo (Para auto llenado deberia tener la tabla mysql en su diseño una pequeña llave llamada Key en ingles de color amarillo en muchos casos ella te dice que el campo se llena solo en otros casos revisa que el diseño te diga que permite valores null) osea esto

```
ID valor_de_digitos ejemplo INT **NOT NULL**
nombre valor_de_digitos ejemplo Varchar(250) NULL
apellido valor_de_digitos ejemplo Varchar(250) NULL
cedula valor_de_digitos ejemplo INT NULL
rango valor_de_digitos ejemplo Varchar(250) NULL
```

**Ya el hecho que la columna te dice NOT NULL significa que no te admite valores NULL**

Comment: y como podria arreglar eso?, sirve bien entonces como estoy recogiendo los datos?, utilice un echo para ver dentro de funciones y si los guarda, pero no se si la función este haciendo bien el llamado.

algo que intente fue colocar el codigo de conexion.php en el misma archivo de funciones, y asi no sale el error de la linea 9, pero no guarda ni inserta nada

Comment: Si elemino la linea function bd_agregar(){ } todo se arregla, que podra pasar?

Comment: Amigo solo revisa que la tabla que usas en tu base datos acepte valores null creo que  si haces una insercion veras cual acepta y cual no osea me esplico si insertas asi con todos los campos full segun leo en tu consulta hay 4 Campos  que debes rellenar y son nombre,apellido,cedula,rango si tienes algun 5 o sexto campo que estes dejando por defecto vacio eso te esta diciendo que o te acepta el valor NULL que viene siendo igual a un vacio.

Comment: en si amigo el problema lo tienes para ser mas exacto es en tu base datos

Comment: yo tengo otro sistema mas completo y trabaja con cedula en vez del id, porque como tal en mi pais, el ID es la cedula, su codigo unico, ya hice funcionar el sistema, pero como escribia mas arriba, me da problemas al usar la FUNCTION, no pasa ningun valor

Answer (score 0):

No estás especificando que haces una conexión. Me explico:

- Tu código: `$cone = new mysqli($host,$usua,$pass,$base);`
- Solución: `$cone = new mysqli_connect($host,$usua,$pass,$base);`

Lo único que debes hacer es cambiar `mysql_connect` por `mysqli_connect`.